# How can I make centering images in LibreOffice Impress easier?

Tags: libreoffice

Centering images manually in LibreOffice Impress can be very tedious.

Is there any way I can automate it or make it easier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just go to *View* → *Snap Lines*  and tick all of the options. Also enable *View* → *Ruler* :

[image]

If you do this you will be able to see the center points of slides and stuff. You can also right click on the object and go to *Alignment* :

[image: Look for Alignment, and the use the 'Centre*' options to centre the object.]

Comment: Is this more what you were looking for? :D

Comment: By the way, to screen-shot menus and stuff, open up the [screen-shot dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j33Ht.jpg), you can set a delay and take a screenshot of the menus.

Comment: Thanks you telling me that!! BTW, for future reference you need to search screenshot in applications to find it. It took me a minute to figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to View->Snap Lines (put the mouse over it)>(Make sure all options are checkmarked) 
Then go to View->Ruler (make sure it is checkmarked to)

If you do this you will be able to see the center points of slides and stuff.